# Most recent rows at least 1 hour apart in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am collecting data every five minutes and entering it into a MySQL database.  I would like to extract the most recent row that's over 2 hours old, followed by over 1 hour old, followed by the most recent row.

I was thinking something along the lines of the following, but I think this will get me the last row of each hour.  Meaning if I run the query at 8:05 I might get back rows from 6:57, 7:57 and 8:02, the last 2 of which are much less than an hour apart.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM mytable 
    ORDER BY Date DESC 
    GROUP BY HOUR(Date) LIMIT 3
) x 
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions you can provide.

Comment: I've reformatted your query. Generally you'll find people don't want to read cryptic and lengthy one-liners. You need to help us to help you :)

Comment: I think that task will help you, take a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM mytable 
  WHERE `Date`<DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR) 
  ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 1
)
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM mytable 
  WHERE `Date`<DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
  ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 1
)
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM mytable 
  ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY `Date`ASC
```

Comment: Simple and able to utilize an index for each part.

Comment: @MarcusAdams ... which were the design goals (plus being as easy to adapt as possible)

Comment: Thanks, this will do what I'm looking for!  Just wondering though, is there a way to do this without a nested query for each hour.  In case I have to go back, say 24 hours in the future.